# How show tagged file from server via checkbox menu?

Tags: php, checkbox

I am making a simple portfolio viewer page for a friend.

She would like to have a folder on the server where she can throw files in, and then have them shown on a webpage. I am trying to do this with `PHP`

```
      var folder = "images/";

$.ajax({
    url : folder,
    success: function (data) {
        $(data).find('a').attr("href", function (i, val) {
          if( val.match(/\.(jpe?g|png|gif)$/)) {
            $("body").append( "<img src='"+ folder + val +"'>" ); }
          if( val.match(/\.(mpe?g|mp4|mov)$/)) {
            $("body").append( "<video height='400' autoplay><source src='"+ folder + val +"'></video>" ); }
          if( val.match(/\.(pdf)$/)) {
            $("body").append( "<embed src='"+ folder + val +"'type='application/pdf' height='500px' width='400px' />" ); }
        }); } });</script>
```

Then she would like a clickable index-menu with checkboxes to show/hide files with the same tag. So for instance: show all files with the tag "video" and "inspiration".

[image]

I thought I could put the tags in the filenames, and then parse them out and use them as a class to give a visible/hidden css to, and even though that all sounds very doable, I don't know which order to write this in and I'm missing php/javascript vocabulaire. Is this idea possible and how would I approach this?

It would look the same as this: https://jsfiddle.net/gptrhze1/2/?fbclid=IwAR0XUcuJCF3_ellJXfXd8oJkqmgieucItokT1UpAmcKHkjP4nJQFPYom5Mk, but here the images are coded in instead of from a folder on the server.

Answer (score 0):

I can just give you my opinion and recommandation how I would approach this.

I think draging files just to the server is not the best way. As you mentioned, you can't really track which files belong to which category. Furthermore she would need to connect to the server from her computer with FTP programm or something else.

I would recommend to create a web interface where she can upload files. This can be easily done with HTML forms, and then evaluate the results in PHP. There are several scripts/ tutorials or other Stackoverflow threads about uploading files to a server in PHP. This can be done easily.

So, to keep track of all the files I would suggest creating/ hosting a database. Create attributes for the filename on the server, category and more. If she uploads a file, you will create a entry in the table. That would be the best way.

Values from the database can be easily accessed with PHP and the result can be shown in HTML. You can also open the files or download them.